# How can redis on aws, trigger a lambda on key expiry?

Tags: node.js, redis, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-elasticache

I have multiple keys in Redis Elasticache and have set the key expiry time to 24 hours. I want to trigger a lambda on each key expiry. I work on Node.js.

Comment: Use pub/sub https://redis.io/topics/notifications. You need to write custom script that will listen on pub/sub. Something like this https://medium.com/@ridwanfajar/using-redis-pub-sub-with-node-js-its-quite-easy-c9c8b4dae79f

Comment: But here is the catch. we don't have a dedicated server running all the time. So we can't do that.

Comment: Use SNS, like here exaplained https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/monitor-amazon-elasticache-for-redis-cluster-mode-disabled-read-replica-endpoints-using-aws-lambda-amazon-route-53-and-amazon-sns/

Comment: I guess SNS triggers lambda instantaneous and doesn't schedule the execution of Lambda Function.

Comment: You have to put lambda listener on sns event